# Meaning of "such a true mistake"

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-difference

What are the differences between these sentences?

> It was a true mistake.
>
> It was **such a** true mistake

Comment: LMS, thx for editing my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences convey the thought that the *mistake* is a *true mistake,* but the second emphasizes the point.

In the second sentence, **such** is used as an *adjective of degree* (as defined in any dictionary, such as [this one](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/such?s=t).) It is employed here as an *intensifier:* it emphasizes the adjective that follows, which is *true*. The sense of your second sentence is "It was an extremely true mistake."

Similarly, we might say:

> It was a good meal.

If the meal was memorable, we might say:

> It was **such** a good meal!

Comment: Initially I was concerned that **true** was not a gradable adjective, and so not eligible for used with intensifiers, but we often use the expressions **very true** and **too true**. This article suggests that **true** can be either gradable or ungradable, depending on the context:- http://www.slideshare.net/Jess_teacher/gradable-and-nongradable-adjectives

Comment: @JavaLatte I just noticed your comment. Yes, I had to look twice at _true_ as well! At first I suspected the OP's sentence was akin to **It is a _very unique_ mistake.**